# Как передать state через combineRedusers или connect

Tags: reactjs, state, redux-middleware

Прошу прощенья за, возможно, глупый вопрос.
До того как разбил редьюсеры на разные файлы все работало нормально. Как только использовал combineReducers все полетело к чертям.:

```
export const rootReduser = combineReducers({
    init: init_reduser,
    sort: sortReduser
})
```

Есть вот такой редьюсер. Не понимаю как передать сюда стейт из редьюсера init в котором сидит простой массив пользователей.

```
const sortResuer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SORT_BY_ID: {
            let newState = _.cloneDeep(state);
            newState.data.data.sort((a, b) => (a.id - b.id)))
            return newState
        }
```

```
const Header = props => {

debugger
    return (
        <div className={s.header}>
            <Button path="" discr="Id" reduser={props.sortById}/>
            <Button path="" discr={props.lang ? props.lang.name : ""}  reduser={props.sortByName} />
            <Button path="" discr={props.lang ? props.lang.age : ""} reduser={props.sortByAge}/>
            <Button path="" discr="Sort" />
            <Button path="/table" discr={props.lang ? props.lang.table : ""}/>
            <Button path="/preview" discr={props.lang ? props.lang.preview : ""} />
            <Button path="" discr="lang" reduser={props.toggleLanguage}/>
            {/* <Search search={props.search}/> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

в connect передаю все вот так:

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            sortById: () => dispatch(sortById())
    }
```

что бы не делал вылетает ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать это во первых антипаттерн.

Так с redux-ом не работают.Их не разделяют чтобы потом достать дату из одного стейта и передать в другую.

`combinereducer` нужно для того чтобы разделить ваш `redux` state.То есть это метод, который позволяет вместо того, чтобы создавать один огромный `reducer` для всего состояния приложения сразу, разбивать его на отдельные модули.

Но если вам нужен дата из `reducer`-а init в `reducer`-е sort то не надо ничего разделять.Пишите просто один глобальный стейт и все.И разделяете только тогда когда увидите что они не зависят друг от друга и вам потом не понадобится  дата из другого `reducer`-а.

В [**документации**](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) написано.

> As your app grows more complex, you'll want to split your reducing
>   function into separate functions, each managing independent parts of
>   the state.

По мере того как ваше приложения будет расти в более сложное, вам захочется разделить вашу функцию в отдельные функции, каждая из которых будет управлять НЕЗАВИСИМЫМИ частями вашего стейта.

(Если перевел не правильно думаю лингвисты меня исправят)

То есть если они не зависят друг от друга ТОЛЬКО ТОГДА их можно разделить.